# Catalyst dispatcher for arbitrary tree-structure

Tags: perl, dispatcher, catalyst

Greetings,

I'm new to Catalyst and I am attempting to implement some dispatch logic.

My database has a table of items, each with a unique `url_part` field, and every item has a parent in the same table, making a tree structure. If `baz` is a child of `bar` which is a child of `foo` which is a child of the root, I want the URL `/foo/bar/baz` to map to this object. The tree can be any depth, and users will need to be able to access any node whether branch or leaf.

I have been looking through the documentation for Chained dispatchers, but I'm not sure if this can do what I want. It seems like each step in a chained dispatcher must have a defined name for the `PathPart` attribute, but I want my URLs to be determined solely by the database structure.

Is this easy to implement with the existing Catalyst dispatcher, or will I need to write my own dispatch class?

Thanks! :)

ETA:

I figured out that I can use an  empty `Args` attribute to catch an arbitrary number of arguments. The following seems to successfully catch  every request under the root:

```
sub default :Path :Args() {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    my $path = $c->request->path;

    $c->response->status( 200 );
    $c->response->body( "Your path is $path" );
}
```

From there I can manually parse the path and get what I need, however, I don't know if this is the best way to accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: P.S. please come by #catalyst on irc.perl.org for more interactive help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with various options, I believe I've arrived at an acceptable solution. Unfortunately, I couldn't get a recursive dispatch going with `:Chained` (Catalyst complains if you try to chain a handler to itself. That's no fun.)

So I ended up using a single handler with a large `CaptureArgs`, like this:

```
sub default : CaptureArgs(10) PathInfo('') { 
    my ( $self, $c, @args ) = @_;

    foreach my $i( 0 .. $#args ) { 
        my $sub_path = join '/', @args[ 0 .. $i ];

        if ( my $ent = $self->_lookup_entity( $c, $sub_path ) ) { 
            push @{ $c->stash->{ent_chain} }, $ent;
            next;
        }

        $c->detach( 'error_not_found' );
    }

    my $chain = join "\n", map { $_->entity_id } @{ $c->stash->{ent_chain} };
    $c->response->content_type( 'text/plain' );
    $c->response->body( $chain );
}
```

If I do a `GET` on `/foo/bar/baz` I get

```
foo
foo/bar
foo/bar/baz
```

which is what I want. If any part of the URL doesn't correspond to an object in the DB, I get a 404.

This works fine for my application, which will never have things ten-levels deep, but I wish I could find a more general solution that could support an arbitrary-depth tree.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the structure of your data, which I'm not completely clear on from your question.

If there is a fixed number of levels (or at least a limited range of numbers of levels) with each level corresponding to a specific sort of thing, then Chained can do what you want -- it's valid (and downright common) to have a chained action with `:CaptureArgs(1) PathPart('')` which will create a `/*/` segment in the path -- that is, it gobbles up one segment of the path without requiring any particular fixed string to show up.

If there's not any such thing -- e.g. you're chasing an unlimited number of levels down an arbitrary tree, then a variadic `:Args` action is probably exactly what you want, and there's nothing dirty in using it. But you don't need to be decoding `$c->req->path` yourself -- you can get the left-over path segments from `$c->req->args`, or simply do `my ($self, $c, @args) = @_;` in your action.
You *can* write a new DispatchType, but it's just not likely to be worth the payoff.

Comment: Thanks hobbs. It is indeed an arbitrarily-deep tree. Right now I'm experimenting with the variadic `:Args` form and getting the path array from `@_`. I wasn't aware of `PathPart('')` which looks like it would be pretty useful, too. I'll do some more playing around. :)